# Imprimir texto en C/c++ con printf

Tags: c++, c

Cómo seria posible imprimir texto y datos al mismo tiempo? Por ejemplo supongamos que tengo una variable x y quiero que me imprima un texto del estilo “el valor de x es &x” (&x seria el valor de x introducido por el usuaio) Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama imprimir una cadena de texto formateada.

En C, lo harías de esta manera:

```
printf("El valor de x es %i", x);
```

Eso si, el `%i` se utiliza para imprimir números enteros. También tienes `%f` para números con coma flotante, entre varios otros. [Aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Formateadores) tienes una tabla con todos los formateadores disponibles.

Suerte!